# What is the correct way to reference properties in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

simple question. I want the shortname of a directory service so i can reference the netbios name elsewhere in a CFN file.

Currently just using a parameter to enter it so i can reuse it later... but the short name defaults to the first part of the domain name ( ex. example.com, the short name is automatically example which is what i want)

the problem is if i don't enter it as a parameter, i have no idea how to just reference it..

Does any syntax exist that is !Ref mydirectory.shortname ? I cannot figure/find any info on it

```
myDirectory:
Type: AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD
Properties:
  Name:
    Ref: directoryName
  Password: 
    Ref: MicrosoftADPW
  ShortName:
    Ref: ${NetBIOSName}
  Edition: Standard
  VpcSettings: 
    SubnetIds: 
      - !Ref PrivateSubnetA
      - !Ref PrivateSubnetB
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

Comment: So your parameter is `myserver.example.com` but you want `myserver`?

Comment: Correct, i just need the shortname of the domain

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with the `Fn::Split` and `Fn::Select` functions (I haven't tested this, and don't usually use YAML syntax so it might not be exact):

```
!Select ["0", !Split[".", !Ref FullyQualifiedName ]]
```

However, I think this is the wrong way to approach the problem, especially if you have to use the short name in multiple places.

Instead, I would create two parameters, one for the domain name and one for the hostname (which you call shortname). Then combine them using `Fn::Sub`:

```
!Sub "${HostName}.${DomainName}"
```

Comment: thanks, this work around should work fine. I was more looking for a myDirectory.ShortName that would be really easy to reference like i can use for DNSIPAddresses